# How to disable auto-suggestion/word-completion in Windows Mobile 6.5 from settings?

Tags: autocomplete, settings, autosuggest, windows-mobile-6.5, word-completion

I want to disable the auto suggestion from 'settings' or some type of UI that comes with the OS. I'm using Motorola MC9595, OS 6.5 professional.

I know a registry which changes this behaviour but given my scenrio, thats not an option for me.  Also I'm finding it hard to disgest that there is no UI for this setting on 6.5, though I was able to change this behaviour in WM 6.(settings/personal/input)

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Windows registry editor (`regedit.exe`) to change it.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Sip]
"SuggWords"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: The user states that editing the registry is not an option for them.